# What type of encryption is this?

Tags: decryption

2018000010 - YjRxEBukq

Encrypted

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

Decrypted

A lady, attempting to avoid revealing her real age, says:
I'm twenty-two years old. If you do not count weekends and one summer month of every year,
guess my real age.

Answer (score 1):

It's [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded binary data, after decoding it (e.g. using the `base64` command line tool in Linux or MacOS) we see it consists of 544 bytes of random looking data. As this is a multiple of 16, we could have data from any 16 (or 8) byte block cipher with some unknown key (e.g AES). You cannot tell what cipher without any additional knowledge.

Answer (score -2):

This is not cipher. I think it is an encoded message.

Reedit:

You can't know what type it is  only from ciphertext. If you can, I think this encryption algorithm is not safe.

Comment: Obviously it is a base-64 text. But this is needed for convenience only, e.g. to easily copy & pate it in a text editor. But if you decode it, then you see the real encrypted message. Its length is 544 bytes. Where as the original message has length 167 bytes. Your answer is not helpful.